# Python 2.5 as keyword with multiple exceptions

Tags: python, exception, keyword

Is there a way to define names for multiple exceptions by using the `as` keyword or the python 2.5 grammar `Exception, e`? So if you define an try/except clause with exceptions in a tuple like this `...except (RuntimeError, TypeError, NameError):` to also assign names to the errors e.g. like `as (Rerr,Terr,Nerr)`?

Or do I **have to** define them separately one by one?

```
try:
    ....
except RuntimeError as Rerr:
    ....
except TypeError as Terr:
    ....
....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But if you need them each named separately, then you're presumably defining separate handler logic for each, in which case what is wrong with the separate definitions?

You can assign a single name to the exception regardless of type:

```
except (RuntimeError, TypeError, NameError) as e:
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with them. I was wondering if it was possible. But the answer of @Daniel Roseman did clarify why this won't work. So thanks to you both.

Answer (score 6):

You've misunderstood what the `as` keyword is doing. It's assigning the exception instance itself to the variable, not the class. So whichever type is caught by the `except`, it will end up in the `as` variable.

Comment: I did, indeed. Thanks for shedding some light onto the dark corners of my knowledge.